# Twig raw filter - documentation confusing

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've attached a snapshot of the Twig documentation for the raw filter, found [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)

I cannot grok what it means.  Can someone please elucidate?  Thankie...

[image: twig raw]

Comment: It basically means that the `raw` filter only marks immediate values as safe. But as long as **any** part of an expression is unsafe the whole expression becomes unsafe (and thus gets escaped before printing it out)

Answer (score 5):

From the same documentation:

> The `raw` filter marks the value as being "safe"

Raw is a filter, thus it does not **render** any output: it just trasforms it. In this case, the "trasformation" consists in setting a "safe" mark on it so that the actual rendering (performed by the `{{...}}` tags) will not escape it.

If you re-read the following examples at the light of this, they should be more clear.

Let's take the second example:

```
{{ false ? hola : hello|raw }}
```

This means: since we cannot know in advance if the condition will be true or false, and since one of the two possibile outcomes is not safe, the whole `{{...}}` **will** escape the output regardless of the "raw" filter.

They are warning you precisely about this kind of "unexpected" behaviour. In such a case you should mark all as "raw":

```
{{ (false ? hola : hello)|raw }}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see it now.  I find it a bit strange, but I suppose that's why they mentioned it.  Why would't the second expression return hello marked as safe?  But it's a rhetorical question and, I suppose, the point of the example...

Comment: I improved my answer focusing on the second example.

Comment: Yes... I would have interpreted it differently otherwise; I would have assumed the _if_ to be hola not marked as raw and the _then_ to be hello marked as raw.  A bit odd, but I assume that's why they mentioned it.